# Лингвистика и программирование

Tags: общие-вопросы

На нашем форуме есть программисты и знатоки языка одновременно. Вопрос к ним. Возможно ли создание такого текстового редактора, чтобы находил все орфографические ошибки. Т.е. прочитывал  бы слово в контексте предложения. Например,  находил бы у причастия зависимое слово, распознавал бы омографы. (Ну не видит редактор слово работа, написанное с О в первом слоге. Ведь есть слово робот).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ларf, так вопрос ставился году в восьмидесятом прошлого века. 
Сейчас перекладывать на компьютер все, что можно и нельзя, стало немодным.
Компьютер (или "программа" в вашем варианте) делает ровно столько, сколько позволяет ей прикладная теория программируемого процесса или явления. 
Что нужно в нашем случае? Перво-наперво нужен мощный грамматический анализатор, позволяющий перемолоть всё многообразие возможностей и выбирать единственно возможный вариант (если он есть). Идея создания такого анализатора носится в воздухе, работы интенсивно ведутся все эти годы, наиболее продвинутые результаты реализованы в компьютерных переводчиках и оффисных редакторах, в первых - даже больше, но по качеству перевода можно судить о состоянии разработок. Оно сейчас ниже чем никакое, особенно в художественных текстах. Причина - невозможность формального описания грамматики. Причем речь идёт не только о состоянии на сей день, но о принципиальной неразрешимости некоторых вопросов. Если вы где-нибыдь в Нацкорпусе русского языка, например, или в чем-то подобном, наткнётесь на помету типа "грамматическая омонимия не снята", знайте, что компьютеру анализ этого текста оказался недоступен.

Вот вам пример, которым я в своё время (начало девяностых) просто-таки задолбал поборников идеи всемогущности компьютерного анализа. "Торговали мы недаром необъявленным товаром" (©АСП). Недаром торговали или недаром необъявленным? А ведь от понимания зависит очень много, возможность раздельного написания "не даром" например. Пока компьютер (точнее - существующая формализация грамматики) не научится решать подобные формально неразрешимые проблемы, о хорошем спелл-чекере заявленного вами уровня нечего и думать.

А ведь это только полдела. Самое сложное - проанализировать фразу, не совсем точно вписывающуюся в грамматические рамки, с эллипсисом, например.

Короче, я не сомневаюсь, что решение этой проблемы - в совместной работе человека и компьютера. Богу - богово, Кесарю - кесарево. Так оно лучше получится.

Простите за ошибки и возможные нестыковки. Править и редактировать написанное сейчас не в состоянии, а ответить очень хотелось, это "моя" тема.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Многие говорят: "Зачем мне Ваш русский, мне компьютер все исправит". Отвечаю, что компьютер не умеет анализировать текст. Скажите, а как сотрудничают лингвисты и программисты в этой работе? Или эти люди и лингвисты, и программисты одновременно? И, простите, что такое "спелл-чекер"? Программа, которая редактирует текст?

Comment: >>>Отвечаю, что компьютер не умеет анализировать текст.   

Ну не то чтобы совсем не умеет, но до должного уровня не доходит. Но Вы совершенно правильно отвечаете, проблема именно в беспомощности современного программного обеспечения и самой математической  лингвистики.

Comment: >>>Скажите, а как сотрудничают лингвисты и программисты в этой работе? Или эти люди и лингвисты, и программисты одновременно?   

Я давно уже "не в теме", но вообще-то в таких проектах "программисты" (в классическом понимании) - это рабочие лошадки. Сотрудничают разработчики, математики и лингвисты, например. А программисты только черной (и черновой) работай занимаются. 

>>>И, простите, что такое "спелл-чекер"? Программа, которая редактирует текст?   

Ошибки находит. На уровне корректора. До редактирования нам пока что как до Луны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически такую программу создать возможно, но, уверен, она будет с огромным количеством ошибок и неполадок, даже если её будут создавать первоклассные программисты, потому что в предложении могут находится несколько слов в нужной форме (для того же причастия). Программа не сможет выбрать. В общем, практически такую программу создать почти невозможно.