# Заменить или поменять?

Tags: синтаксис

Word регулярно подчеркивает мне выражения типа "заменим вектор на сумму...", при этом указывает, что с подобным управлением используется глагол "поменять". А *заменить* можно только *чем-то*. Наверное, это так и есть, но у меня "правильные" конструкции как-то не ложатся на слух и я просто игнорирую подсказку.

Действительно, "поменяем вектор на сумму ..." я точно не напишу, в конце концов "замена" здесь практически математический термин. Да и смысл немного другой.

Но и "заменим вектор суммой ..." как-то не смотрится. Тем более, если *то, что* и *то, чем* заменяют описано распространенными конструкциями.

В общем, вопрос ребром: быть или не быть послушной стандартной грамматике?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как по мне, то вроде все смотрится: "заменим вектор суммой..." Вряд ли грамматический анализатор здесь ошибается. Я бы не рискнула по-другому.

Comment: Ничего, я смелая! Думаю, если текст идет в "большую печать", редакторы поправят.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Не дождётесь.
По большому счету уровень грамматических анализаторов сейчас не намного ушёл от первых попыток 1980 г. что-то поправить в этой консерватории. Я, правда, давно уже отошел от темы, но если судить по тому же ворду и прочим переводчикам... Причина не в лени или глупости разработчиков. Естественные грамматики неформализуемы. 
Вообще я достаточно подробно писал об этом... Сейчас попробую найти.

Да. [Вот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: Ой, а чего я не дождусь? Идеального анализатора? Да я и не жду, понимаю сложность задачи.  

Мой вопрос попроще: можно все-таки "заменить на" или нет? Что говорит по этому поводу начальник транспортного цеха? Тьфу, то бишь официальная наука?

Comment: Не вижу необходимости. Ворду нельзя доверять. Да и на слух "заменить" лучше.  
Интересно, а в "замена переменной", ворд тоже предложит "подмена"?

Comment: Он не предлагает "подмену", просто пишет, что это слово влияет не появление ошибки. Предлагает творительный падеж.

Comment: Наверно, Вы имели ввиду творительный: замена кем? чем?.

Comment: @inna, ну конечно творительный! Просто невнимательность! Спасибо за замечание! Жаль, уже не могу отредактировать.  
Впрочем, не только невнимательность: я как-то подзабыла термины, размылись они у меня (((. Надо начать заниматься с сыном: заодно и сама вспомню!

Comment: Дамы, о чем вы? 
Какая невнимательность?)))

Comment: Это к вопросу "не могу отредактировать".  
"Есть многое на свете, друг Горацио..."

Comment: Ну, я так и подумала! Да Вы шутник, батенька! 

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ворд прав. Управление слова заменить-что чем, поменять-что на что. Но здесь присутствует метонимия: Вы же не вектор меняете, а слово. Ворд метонимию засчитывает за ошибку, потому что он различает только прямые значения. Если хотите сказать абсолютно правильно, скажите так:заменим слово "вектор" на слово"сумма..."
Или придётся пренебречь советами Ворда о грамотной речи и писать так, как привыкли.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но вообще-то я не слово меняла, а подставляла в формулу вместо одного объекта другой (вместо одного вектора - сумму векторов). Думаю, у меня просто индивидуальная речевая ошибка, от которой я никак не хочу отказаться...

Comment: Я не вижу ошибки. Это обычный математический язык (не хочу двже говорить "жаргон"), которому Ворд не обучен. 
Насчет метонимии - не совсем понял. Меняем мы именно *вектор*, никакое не "слово". На сумму. 
Не очень понял математическое основание (это ж не шило на мыло, объекты разной сущности: сумма - скаляр), но явно речь идет об объектах, а не "словах".